# Remove alias from home page (MODX Revolution)

Tags: .htaccess, modx, modx-revolution

In the current time I have https://roto.com.ua/ua/index in my web site in MODX Revolution. My Friendly URL'S have also settings.
 Also I have 2 contexts (ukrainian,russian), anybody can help me remove /index alias from my web root page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Babel extra, right? If not, check it out [here](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/babel). If you do, as I recall, in such a case you have to choose 1 context which will open the default language version of your site on your-site.com (lets say it is in Russian). The added language context will be available on your-site.com/ua/. If you get `index` in the URL you are doing something wrong. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSa_CdinTUE) by Menno Pietersen on how to enable several language contexts for a modx site using Babel extra. If you are not comfortable with watching in English, check this [guide](https://my-webdev-notes.blogspot.ru/2016/01/modx-babel.html) in Russian which is based on that video.

Comment: hmmm... I don't know, what is problem with context.. Look i have screen photo https://prnt.sc/gaspjg for you) I have correct settings for contexts also for rus. But not working( I have https://roto.com.ua/ua/index with alias at the end url....

Comment: hi! 'uk' doesn't stand for Ukraine. It is United Kingdom. Also I see 403 error when I try to access https://roto.com.ua/ua/. As for "index" in the url - check again settings that enable seo-friendly urls (inside CMS and in .htaccess), check document's properties (alias), Wayfinder/PDOtools responsible for forming urls and also check whether you strictly followed all the steps in the guides.

Comment: Do you have the `site_start` setting on your context? That's how MODX figures out what resource to load as homepage for a context. MODX automatically ignores the alias for the homepage.